# Mouse Up event bottleneck-ing my animation?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a modal window gallery coded by hand, and the performance when loading and unloading the modal is very slow (down to 1-2 FPS) which is very noticeable. That's without transitions; just setting display to none.

I did a performance review, and that's what leads me to my question. When closing the modal, it took 500ms to hide, of which 300ms is "Other". The only other I can find is the Mouse Up event.

Should this take that long (i.e. run the duration of the script it triggers)? Any other ideas what the bottleneck could be if Scripting, Rendering, and Painting is not the issue judging by their times?[image]

Comment: For performance that slow, you're likely in a code loop, or triggering some sort of custom event handler rapid-fire. Usual culprits: `onscroll` or `onresize` event handlers, or click handlers that accidentally retrigger themselves by calling `.click()` in code. Any of that sound promising?

Comment: It's very possible. I haven't even dug into the script to look yet, to be honest. But the reason is because of that 2.1ms scripting time. Maybe that doesn't include listeners? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try exposing built-in V8 stuff: go to `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments` and enable it, restart Chrome, go to devtools, settings, experiments, tap Shift key 6 times, select all Timeline-related experiments.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  Enabling all the experiments didn't actually give any more data - it's just in "Mouse Up" for a very long time while idle.  We're talking 15-20 seconds here.